# I need precompile assets every time I've made any change to see difference in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, assets, browser-refresh

Like as I mentioned in title - I have to precompile assets every time I've made any change to see how it looks like - I've tried `config.assets.compile = true`, without success.

I've also tried `RAILS_ENV = 'development'` but with same effect. Please help me because it is really annoying.

My system is running on:

- Xubuntu
- Rails -v: 3.1.1
- Ruby -v: 1.9.2p290

I also tried:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

One cause of this could be that you ran `rake assets:precompile` once. The server then uses `public/assets` exclusively, without trying to compile your assets on the fly.

Try removing the `public/assets` directory.

Comment: yes, I ran once 'rake assets:precompile'. I deleted public/assets but still my browser don't see my changes - but this time I don't have to run 'rake:precompile' but just restart server - but it is still annoying :/

Comment: @ofcapl are you sure you're in the development environment?

Comment: yes, I'm pretty sure - but problem solved - probably after deleting 'public/assets' - it worked after whole system restart[weird o_O] :) thanks :)